# OpenID Connect's Implicit Flow is available in Salesforce?

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, open-id-connect

I'm trying to login to Salesforce by Implicit Flow using third-party OpenID Provider on localhost.

After authentication and authorization on the OP, it responds Access Token and ID Token to Salesforce,
but Salesforce redirects to the error page as follows,

```
https://example-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?
  ErrorCode=No_Oauth_State&ErrorDescription=State+was+not+sent+back#access_token=eyJ...&
  scope=profile+email+openid&
  id_token=eyJ...&
  state=Lu5...&
  token_type=Bearer&
  expires_in=600
```

I'm using Connect2id server 2.3.2 as OP.
It seems that the OP sent back the state value
which is same as one received from Salesforce with Authentication Request.

Security Control | Auth. Provider | Authorize Endpoint URL is set as follows,

```
https://localhost:8443/c2id-login-page-js?response_type=id_token%20token&nonce=xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Got any solution for this? I got it with twitter.

Comment: No. I think Salesforce does not support Implicit Flow. 
I think there is no choise but to select Authorization Code Flow and
to deploy OP to the place where Salesforce can access to.